# Remove items from UIMenuController using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I want to know how to do two things:

1. Remove the UIMenuController entirely. I want the text in WKWebView to be selected, but the UIMenuController is causing issues when the long press is released.

   2. Add a new items to the list of menu items, and remove others.

Right now I can add an item to the end of the list, but nothing else, using the following code.

```
func enableCustomMenu() {
    let lookup = UIMenuItem(title: "Add comment", action: "addComment")

    UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = [lookup]
}

func disableCustomMenu() {
    UIMenuController.sharedMenuController().menuItems = nil
}

func addComment() {
    //let text = self.webView.("window.getSelection().toString();")
    print("Add Comment")
}
```